how to configure Sitecore CLI in Azure app services
I want to configure Sitecore CLI in Azure app services (TEST-CM Sitecore 10.3 site)
And want to Serialize Sitecore Content on Azure site (TEST-CM)
So, anyone have a setup steps of the Sitecore CLI on azure

We wrote a full blog on this maybe it can help you: https://www.blastic.com/blog/sitecore/simplifying-item-serialization-in-sitecore-with-sitecore-cli/
